How to enable a virtual display with headless mode in seleniumbase?
with SB(uc=True, Headless=True) as sb:
    for url in urls:
        sb.uc_open_with_reconnect(url, 5)
        sb.uc_gui_handle_captcha()
        time.sleep(2)
        has_next_page = True

I'm facing a website with a CAPTCHA. In NON HEADLESS mode, that code works properly, but in headless mode, it doesn't because sb.uc_gui_handle_captcha() needs PyAutoGUI, and in headless mode, PyAutoGUI can't run.
I read in the seleniumbase documentation that the SB manager includes a special virtual display that allows for PyAutoGUI actions. How can i enable that virtual display so that my code will work properly in headless mode?
I expect that the code will run in headless mode, and that sb.uc_gui_handle_captcha() can bypass the CAPTCHA with headless mode.

Use the SeleniumBase Xvfb virtual display to simulate headless mode in a headless environment on Linux:
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True, xvfb=True) as sb:
    urls = [URL1, URL2]
    for url in urls:
        sb.uc_open_with_reconnect(url, 5)
        sb.uc_gui_click_captcha()
        sb.sleep(2)
        # Do more stuff here

(Don't mix regular headless mode with UC Mode, as PyAutoGUI needs a regular browser to interact with it. Xvfb replaces headless mode in Linux environments.)

is there a way to set display size here?

I've set the sb.cdp.set_window_rect() to 1920x1080 in a Docker container with the xvfb=True and the resize works (checked with a screenshot test). I just wonder if the cpd gui / pyautogui functions will still work since the Xvfb_launcher.sh file is set to 1280x1024x16.

You can change those dimensions with xvfb_metrics="width,height"
